# TCPDF: more image inside multicell

Tags: php, image, tcpdf

is it possible to put multiple images inside a MultiCell in TCPDF?
i tried with this code:

```
$imgArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $imgArray[] = $pdf->Image(IMGS . 'nd.jpg', '', '', 39, 40);
}
$pdf->MultiCell($wLeft, $hRows, implode($imgArray), 0, 'L', FALSE, 0, '', '', TRUE);
```

but i see only one image, and at the top of the image there are three zeros.
i didn't find any example on the web!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`writeHTMLCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246) and `<img />` tag like this :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
    $imgs .= '<img src="'.IMGS.'nd.jpg"/>';

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(170, null, 10, 10, $imgs."\n");
```

---

If you want to use [`Image()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352), set position of each image :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $pdf->Image(IMGS . 'nd.jpg', ($i * 39), 10, 39, 40);
```

In this example, you use `$i` to set horizontal (x) position.
If your image width is 39, each image will be side by side.